# I am what you might find in a ghost town

Tags: riddle, rhyme

My prefix will shut you down,

my suffix a common noun.

My infix desirable to fit in a gown,

I am what you might find in a ghost town.

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> nothing?

My prefix will shut you down,

> NO

my suffix a common noun.

> a THING

My infix desirable to fit in a gown,

> THIN

I am what you might find in a ghost town.

> You might find NOTHING in a ghost town.

Comment: Damn, sniped again.

Comment: A little to obvious? :)

Comment: The "ghost town" clue gave it away for me, after that the hardest part was finding how the infix fit. Great puzzle though! :)

Answer (score 6):

I know there's already an accepted answer. I'd like to point out that another is possible that (to my mind) works almost exactly equally well.

It's

> NOBODY

and its parts are

> NO (same as for NOTHING), BOD (instead of THIN; a little too slangy for my taste but is indeed a desirable thing to fit into a gown), BODY (a common noun, about as much so as THING)

and of course

> a ghost town contains NOBODY much more literally than it contains NOTHING (it presumably still has buildings, for instance; what makes it a ghost town is *precisely* the absence of (living) bodies.

Comment: I like this answer too! (+1) from me :)

Comment: Another great answer!